# Connecting two AWS VPC Regions of the same CIDR range

Tags: vpn, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, cidr

Let say I have two VPC's (VPC-A with 10.50.0.0/16 and VPC-B with 10.50.0.0/16) in AWS with same conflicting/overlapping CIDR ranges in my AWS account. I already have the two VPC's fully functional with 100 plus instances running in either of the VPC's. I am now in great need for the two vpc's to communicate which has the same CIDR ranges. Is there a possible solution that can make the two VPC's communicate to each other. Can this be achieved by establishing a VPN tunnel (though I have same CIDR range). Any suggestions/solutions on this would be highly helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this without introducing a very large amount of complexity, resource contention, and instability into the environment.

You'll just need to buckle down and renumber one of the VPCs.

Comment: Thanks for the update, But does this link strike any cord...  I do not fully understand the remediation that has been proposed. But as said in the solution.. Is there a way?? 
http://serverfault.com/questions/470021/aws-one-vpc-with-multiple-vpn-connections-to-different-sites-what-about-cidr-o

Comment: Of course there's a way. That way is a horrible thing to do, though.

Comment: Unfortunately, AWS does not allow to set up peering between to networks with the same CIDR.  I thought the easy solution would be to add a second interface and put that new interface into a new VPC such that all instances with a second interface can share, as needed.  The second internal interface is allowed for instances without a public interface, but AWS would not allow me to add the second interface to a second VPC regardless of the CIDR :-(  So, my thinking for an 'easy' fix for AWS is just to allow the additional interfaces to go into any VPC.